# How do I use 2 digit years on the horizontal axis for Google Charts library?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, chartkick

I'm using ChartKick gem and Google Charts library. HAML:

```
= line_chart @data.group(:date).average(:measure), discrete: true, library: {hAxis: {slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 45, gridlines: {units: {years: {format: 'yy'}}}}}
```

Results so far:

[image]

Docs: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options and http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details

I also tried

```
hAxis: {format: 'yy-MM-dd', slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 45}
```

Also, how do I stop from truncating the labels?

Answer (score 1):

I use [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem for rails. My line chart:

```
= line_chart Visit.group(:user_id).group_by_day(:created_at, format: "%d %b").count, discrete: true
```

In your case you can use something like this:

```
group_by_year(:date, format: "%y-%m-%d")
```

I hope it helps

Comment: `#group_by_day` doesn't support `#average` so I can't use it. I only support `#count` which is not what I need.

Comment: After hours of searching. This solution worked. Thanks.